# If NULL turn false

Tags: php, if-statement, header, null

So I have an if else statment that check if `loggedIn` is `true` or `false`, it never comes out to be false, rather `NULL`. So what I want to do is turn any `NULL` result `false`, simply because I then get this error

> Undefined index: loggedIn

And it then won't let my `header` run. So is this possible? Convert `NULL` to `false`?

Here's how I set the session

```
$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
```

Comment: Show the code that sets the sessions.

Comment: `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;` @Darren

Comment: `Undefined index` doesn't mean `null`.

Comment: Well I get that because loggedin is returning null. Since I call it before the header @bansi

Comment: We need all the code @user3100859. do you call `session_start()` before setting the session and before calling it?

Comment: in the else part set `$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = false;` or when checking use `if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'])`

Comment: Try to do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` to check if your really utilizing the global `$_SESSION`, otherwise, see @Darren's comment. :)

Comment: Its returning `NULL`.... @lodev09

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll have a crack at this. Lets start with the error message you say you received:

> Undefined index: loggedIn

*What does that mean?*

- Well that usually means that the session key `loggedIn` is not present (meaning it wasn't set).

*How do I test for it?*

Well thats simple enough, all you have to do is use [`isset()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && !empty($_SESSION['loggedIn'])) {...
```

As you can see above, that will check to ensure the `loggedIn` session **is** set and **is not** empty.

Now on to the issue, I presume you haven't used [`session_start`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before trying to start the session you'd like.

Try something like this at the very top of your script that sets the session:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
// has to be called before starting session
session_start();

$_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
```

And on the page where you check the session validity you'd do something like this:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']) && $_SESSION['loggedIn'] !== FALSE) {
    //..... the user is logged in...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if index loggedin is set.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'])
{
  //user is loggedin
}
else
{
 //user is not logged in.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution of converting `NULL` to `false` is ugly. First, you need to know why it is you think that `$_SESSION['loggedIn']` is converting to `NULL` (which you said it's **undefined index**). You can debug it by:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
// print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: How would this answer my question? I know why I'm getting `Undefined index: loggedIn`

Comment: Taka a look at @Darren's answer. It will give you the whole idea

Answer (score -1):

add a condition if loggedIn is null or false return false ;)